# Bootstrap 3 collapse others

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to create a collapsing boxes like in the image below. I need to show couple of boxes like that but want to hide others whenever one collapsible box is open. Tried using bootstrap collapse but looks like there is a issue where the DOM structure is *required*: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10966

Is there any other way to achieve the same behavior without javascript?

[image]

This is what I have as markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-10">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2"><span class="text-uppercase">Var dates</span><span>$600.00</span><span><a data-target="#moreInfoPastAmount" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="moreInfoPastAmount" data-parent="#moreInfo">+Past Amount</a></span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2"><span class="text-uppercase">Var dates</span><span>$400.00</span><span><a data-target="#moreInfoLateFees" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="moreInfoLateFees" data-parent="#moreInfo">+Late Fees</a></span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2"><span class="text-uppercase">Mar 26</span><span>$200.00</span><span>Current Due</span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="moreInfo" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="moreInfoPastAmount" class="arrow-box collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
                <div class="arrow left"></div>
                <p>Content goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div id="moreInfoLateFees" class="arrow-box collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
                <div class="arrow left"></div>
                <p>Content goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of researching, you just need to add a `.panel` class inside your `#moreInfo` div, due to a bug in Bootstrap's collapse data-parent - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10966.

```
<div id="moreInfo" class="row">
        <div class="panel col-xs-12"> <!-- Panel added here -->
            <div id="moreInfoPastAmount" class="arrow-box collapse" aria-expanded="true">
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19434/)

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this without javascript ;)

Comment: @KeithW. Sorry for missing that when reading your question. I've updated my answer, all you need to do is add the panel class.